# 4K Clip Editing with moviepy

Tags: python, image-processing, moviepy

I hope to zoom a 4k video.
The reason is simply I don't have a high resolution monitor.

```
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip
import moviepy.video.fx.all as vfx
clip = VideoFileClip(file_name)
resized_clip = clip .crop(clip, x1=0, y1=0, x2=1920, y2=1080)
```

It is the code I used to cut off the upper-right of 4k clip.
This type of size modifying was worked for other sizes of video, but not worked for 4k.
How can I fix it?

p.s.
Not worked with error.

Comment: "not worked" isn't enough to go by. What happened, what didn't happen? Did you get an error?

Comment: In addition, you really shouldn't use Moviepy to crop a video just for display, since it'll require re-encoding the file; just do it in your player...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `vfx.crop` instead of `clip.crop`.

The correct syntax is:

```
clip = VideoFileClip(file_name)
resized_clip = vfx.crop(clip, x1=0, y1=0, x2=1920, y2=1080)
resized_clip.write_videofile("crop.mp4")
```

The following syntax also works:

```
clip = VideoFileClip(file_name)
clip.crop(x1=0, y1=0, x2=1920, y2=1080).write_videofile("crop.mp4")
```

---

Cropping the top left corner is not the best solution for reducing the resolution.

You are probably looking for [resize](https://zulko.github.io/moviepy/ref/videofx/moviepy.video.fx.all.resize.html):

```
clip = VideoFileClip(file_name)
clip.resize((1920, 1080)).write_videofile("resized.mp4")
```